# Node.js in docker-compose container can't access resource using absolute path

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I'm having Node.js that I'm trying to dockerize. There is a piece of code that provides Google Application Credentials stored in serviceAccount.json file that looks like this:

```
const googleApplicationCredentials = config.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS;
const serviceAccount = require(googleApplicationCredentials);

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: "https://databasename.firebaseio.com"
});
```

Path to this credential file is pulled from docker-compose which looks like this:

```
  api:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./server
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./server:/app
    environment:
      - GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/app/serviceAccount.json"
```

Docker file is this:

```
FROM node:14.14.0-alpine
WORKDIR "/app"
COPY ./package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

When I ssh to docker container, I can see serviceAccount.json under working directory /app.
However, when I start docker-componse I'm getting the following error:

```
Cred:"/app/serviceAccount.json"
api_1     | internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
api_1     |   throw err;
api_1     |   ^
api_1     |
api_1     | Error: Cannot find module '"/app/serviceAccount.json"'
api_1     | Require stack:
api_1     | - /app/src/firebaseInit.js
api_1     | - /app/src/services/notification.service.js
api_1     | - /app/src/controllers/messages.controller.js
api_1     | - /app/src/routes/consultingchannel.routes.js
api_1     | - /app/src/express.js
api_1     | - /app/src/server.js
api_1     |     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
api_1     |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
api_1     |     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
api_1     |     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
api_1     |     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/src/firebaseInit.js:8:24)
api_1     |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
api_1     |     at Module._compile (/app/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:99:24)
api_1     |     at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
api_1     |     at Object.newLoader [as .js] (/app/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:104:7)
api_1     |     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
api_1     |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
api_1     |     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
api_1     |     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
api_1     |     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/src/services/notification.service.js:4:1)
api_1     |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
api_1     |     at Module._compile (/app/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:99:24)
api_1     |     at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
api_1     |     at Object.newLoader [as .js] (/app/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:104:7)
api_1     |     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
api_1     |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
api_1     |     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
api_1     |     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18) {
api_1     |   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
api_1     |   requireStack: [
api_1     |     '/app/src/firebaseInit.js',
api_1     |     '/app/src/services/notification.service.js',
api_1     |     '/app/src/controllers/messages.controller.js',
api_1     |     '/app/src/routes/consultingchannel.routes.js',
api_1     |     '/app/src/express.js',
api_1     |     '/app/src/server.js'
api_1     |   ]
api_1     | }
api_1     | [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
client_1  | Compiled with warnings.
```

**UPDATE:**
Finally realized very obvious problem. I should not have quotes around environment variable. Correct entry should be:

```
environment:
      - GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/app/serviceAccount.json
```

Answer (score 0):

See your volumes definition in docker-compose, you mount your /server directory to /app. I guess that explains why it works when you ssh into the container, while it doesn't when you `docker-compose up` - in the latter case no volume is mounted.

```
volumes:
  - /app/node_modules
   # The culprit?
  - ./server:/app
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what are you suggesting here. server is directory on my host which contains serviceAccount.json file in the root. In docker-compose this volume is mapping server directory from the host to /app in docker container. When I run docker-compose and SSH to the container initialized with it, I see that file, which means the volume is mounted. At least that's how I understand it. However, during that initialization, node.js server fails to startup because it can't find this file.

Comment: In order to test if it's something related to volumes, I've completely removed volumes from docker-compose.yml and added "COPY ./serviceAccount.json /usr/" into Dockerfile. This file is copied now available to the container as /usr/serviceAccount.json, but node code still generates same error, just with different location Error: Cannot find module '"/usr/serviceAccount.json"'

Comment: Hey, did you ever solve this problem ? I also have this problem.